# How do I link an XSD to an XML file in Eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse

How do I link an XSD to an XML file in Eclipse?

The xml file that I am editing is not in the same directory as the xsd file but both are in the workspace.

Answer (score 18):

- Go to Preferences > XML > XML Catalog, and click Add.
- Under Location, enter the path of your XSD file, relative to the workspace.
- Under Key Type, select Schema Location.
- Under Key, enter something like `http://www.yourcompany.com/schema/yourSchema.xsd`.

Then, in your XML files that use that schema, put this at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yourDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.yourcompany.com/schema/yourSchema.xsd">
```

You may need to right-click the XML file and select Validate for it to recognize the new schema.

Comment: Note that you need to use a well-formed URL as your `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` in the XML file, and also as the "Key" in the XML Catalog, or Eclipse won't be able to find it.  I struggled for a while with an XML file that just had `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="foo.xsd"`, and Eclipse's XML Catalog wouldn't find it.  After adding the rest of the URL in the XML file and the XML Catalog (it can even be a fictional URL for testing purposes), it started working.

Comment: I used unix notation for current directory since the file is in the same package/directory: `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./foo.xsd"`. This works like a charm for me  (Eclipse Oxygen)

Answer (score 0):

Use in your XML file the following notation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yourDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.yourcompany.com/schema platform:/resource/yourEclipseProjectInWorkspace/foo/bar/yourSchema.xsd">
```

I used this in Eclipse NEON.3 (4.6.3).